# Drawing a Cylinder around an Arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, geometry

I have the following piece of code to draw an arc and then a velocity vector perpendicular to that curve.  I would like to have a transparent cylinder around the green arrow, what would be easiest way of doing this? ie. so the arrow goes through the top of the cylinder.

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Triangle]
\shade [top color=white, bottom color=gray!50, middle color=white]
  (120:8/3) arc (120:190:8/3) node [black, near end, left] {$\omega$}
  -- (190:25/9) -- (200:15/6) -- (190:20/9) -- (190:7/3)
  arc (190:120:7/3) -- cycle;
\foreach \i in { 210}{
  \draw [->, thick, blue!50!cyan] (\i-65:2) arc (\i-65:\i+60:2);
  \tikzset{shift={(\i:2)}, rotate=\i+180}
  \draw [->, very thick, orange] (0,0) -- (1,0)
    node [black, near end, anchor=\i+90] {$\vec a$};
  \draw [->, very thick, green!50!black] (0,0) -- (0,-2)
    node [black, near end, anchor=\i+180] {$\vec v$};
  \fill circle [radius=1/10];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \fill[draw=orange!50,fill=orange!50] (-3,-1) rectangle (0.5,1);
        \filldraw[fill=orange!20] (-3,0) ellipse (0.5 and 1);
        \fill[fill=orange!50] (.5,-1) arc(-90:90:.5 and 1);
        \draw[line width=5pt, red] (-4,0) -- (-2.5,0);
        \draw[-latex,line width=5pt, red] (1,0) -- (2,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**ADD**: If You want someting like this:

[image]

modify only the first line of picture envitonment:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,rotate=30]
```